# Piloting Examples for Bebop Autonomy on Ubuntu 16

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There were good examples for the take off, landing and emergency commands but no example of what the piloting commands should look like. I tried the same layouts as the take off line but these did not work.

eg. rostopic pub --once bebop/angular.z [1] geometry_msgs/Twist

Any examples of piloting commands would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273830/piloting-examples-for-bebop-autonomy-on-ubuntu-16/) by [jfursdon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32295/jfursdon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new in ROS but I found this on ROS wiki:
http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic

```
$ rostopic pub --once bebop/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 1.0}}'
```

I hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [eLeKtRoN](https://answers.ros.org/users/36187/elektron/) with karma: 16 on 2018-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0